# UICollectionView reloadData more than once - Facing a big major issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I just want to create a UICollectionView as a linear list. That is if the user enters a 4 values in 4 repeats of the textfield, The text has to store in the MutableArray (Which determines the number of collection items).

The problem what I am facing is,

When the view appears, the collectionview starts loading. Initially, data is 0. So, after completion of inserting object in the array. The change should reflect in the Collectionview too. So, after reloading the collectionview, the first item is shown. But, from the next repeats, The data which is recently, entered in the array is inherited to all the cells. Please, help me what to do.

        `howmanypeople=[routescore.text intValue];
        [self.collectionView reloadData]; // Reloading the view`

This code is for item at indexPath :-

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *identifier = @"cvCell2";

static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;

if(!nibMyCellloaded)
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle: nil];
    [collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
    nibMyCellloaded = YES;
}
 cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_lomobile_transit_scooter_small.png"];
    cell.cellabel.text=route;
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor]
  return cell;
```

}

Comment: Post the entire method. There is not enough code here to diagnose the problem. Also where are you defining `cell`?

Comment: Edit your question and post the entire body of the method. This is too difficult to read. At a glance it looks like you have several errors here though. You are referencing instance variables to configure the cell that don't actually change based on the index. Where are you getting `route` and  `howmanypeople`? You should also not be setting the delegate for the `collectionView` every time this method is called. You should be setting it only once. The fact that the method was called at all shows that it was already set, so why are you resetting it?

Comment: it's hard to understand what your code is doing, but what I do in such case 
to detect the problem, is loading the data into cell only with user taps.
meaning load the viewController with empty data.
then tap some button and load what you want, tap other button and add more data, this way you can test better what is going wrong.

Comment: The code wants to perform as the following :- 

Initially, array is empty (So, it is no items displayed in the collectionview)
If one data is entered using Textfield, The array and the collectionview has to be updated. Similarly, for deletion.

Also, regarding my issue, if I enter one value, while entering another value, the table needs to reloaded. So, The recently added values are replicated also to the previous cells


I hope you understood my problem

Comment: @PradheepNarendran : Found any solution? 
If yes, it would be very helpful if you could post the answer too.

Comment: Yea I got a solution like storing the values in an array and when the reloadData is called, The cellforItemAtIndexPath will load the items with [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and it is working fine. If you can't understand, Please let me know and I'll share the code.